# update the content of a page once the renderContenOn: in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

How do I update the content of a page once the `renderContenOn:` has been called? As in the page has been rendered but when user clicks on submit button I have a callback and I need to update the same page.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, unless you specifically want to update in-place, you do not have to do anything. Seaside automatically re-renders the page after it has executed an action callback. Take a look at the **Fundamentals** chapter of the [online seaside book](http://book.seaside.st/). It explains very well how Seaside rendering works and what happens after an action callback was processed.

If you need more complex update behavior (using ajax for example), you can use the included jQuery-Ajax bindings.

Answer (score 3):

If staying on the same page is crucial, you probably want to use one of the JavaScript libraries, for example, the jQuery bindings.

**Use AJAX**

If you downloaded or installed Seaside for Pharo or Squeak, you can find jQuery examples
right in your image. Browse them at `http://localhost:8080/javascript/jquery` or `http://localhost:8080/javascript/jquery-ui`, when using the standard port.

One of the examples is a simple AJAX component, that replaces or alteres content on the current page:

```
JQAjaxFunctionalTest>> renderContentOn: html
    html code id: #logger; with: DateAndTime now.
    html paragraph: [
        html submitButton
            onClick: (html jQuery ajax
                script: [ :s | s << (s jQuery: #logger) html: DateAndTime now ]);
            with: 'Replace'.
        html submitButton
            onClick: (html jQuery ajax
                script: [ :s | s << (s jQuery: #logger) prepend: DateAndTime now ]);
            with: 'Prepend'.
        html submitButton
            onClick: (html jQuery ajax
                script: [ :s | s << (s jQuery: #logger) append: DateAndTime now ]);
            with: 'Append' ]
```

Note that you need a jQuery Library configured for your application, for example by using this:

```
| application |
"your application, eg, when you register it:
application := WAAdmin register: MyRootComponent asApplicationAt: 'myApp'.
"
application preferenceAt: #scriptGeneratorClass put: JQScriptGenerator.
application addLibrary: JQDeploymentLibrary.
```

This should suffice to dynamically alter the content on your currently rendered page.

**Let Ajaxifier use AJAX for you**

The jQuery bindings for Seaside come with an *ajaxifier* that will transform normal calls 
into ajax requests for you so that you do not need to use jQuery yourself.

Just configure your application as:

```
| application |
"your application, eg, when you register it:
application := WAAdmin register: MyRootComponent asApplicationAt: 'myApp'.
"
application preferenceAt: #scriptGeneratorClass put: JQScriptGenerator.
application
    preferenceAt: #sessionClass put: WAExpirySession;
    addLibrary: JQDeploymentLibrary;
    addLibrary: JQAjaxifierLibrary/.
```

and use `#call:` as usual.

Comment: thanks will check it out had one more question while adding my project to http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/ but when I do commit in monticello I get following error "ZnHttpUnsuccessful : 501 Not Implemented"

Comment: did a Monticello “copy” work? If not, please open a new Question :)